# How to implement ASP.NET MVC fetching its information from a remote web-service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I have an android application which fetch its information from a web-service which itself apply some rules to information read from database and returns it to android application.

Currently I'm going to develop a web application which mimics android application and use it temporarily for iOS users.
I'm going to use an ASP.NET MVC application for this purpose (since I know ASP.NET MVC) and implement it like architecture represented in below picture:

[image]

Prior to this I have developed web-api and asp.net MVC application but both of theme were reading information from **database** but currently I'm going to read information from a **remote webservice** and I don't know how to do this?

I want to know which method or APIs should I use to fetch information from remote database and populate my models.

Comment: if you have already deployed the web service , then you need just UI layer. i.e. Asp.net MVC to consume the services using HttpClient with best practices. Just google it you will get alots of articles.

Answer (score 1):

For the actual retrieval of data, you can use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) to send requests to your remote web service and get data from it.

For accessing the data internally, you can do this by implementing the [Repository pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-design#the-repository-pattern) to create the internal interface(s) for getting data to your controllers (or services first if needed).